# Will a solution undissolve if left for a long time?

Tags: physical-chemistry

Simple questions:

1. In a solution of NaCl (aq) that is unsaturated, will the Na and Cl ions eventually start collecting in the bottom of the container because of gravity pulling them down?

OR

2. Will ions in an unsaturated solution be distributed evenly if left out for a long time (assuming no reaction with air, just the force of gravity pulling the ions down)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the dissolution of salt affect the solution density?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/198213/)

Comment: See also [Diffusion vs Gravity in water: does a dissolved ion tend to "sink"?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/173800)

Answer (score 0):

When salt is dissolved in water it means the salt molecules are surrounded by water molecules which are attached by electric forces.

Since electric forces are much stronger than gravitational forces, gravity won't undo the solution.

But... as salt water is denser than pure water, the water will tend to be more salty the lower down. Although at room temperature for a small glass of water, the random movements of the molecules would tend to keep the solution more mixed.

And... if you wait long enough by *pure chance* the salt molecules may all be at the bottom. But then it would almost immediately become mixed again.